# require is not defined in react while working with Chatbot

Tags: reactjs

I'm new in React JS, i'm setting up chatbot in react.
I'm facing `ReferenceError: require is not defined` error

How to solve this problem.

```
var ChatBot  = require('react-simple-chatbot');

const steps = [
  {
    id: '0',
    message: 'Welcome to react chatbot!',
    trigger: '1',
  },
  {
id: '1',
message: 'Bye!',
end: true,
 },
 ];

ReactDOM.render(
   <div>
    <ChatBot steps={steps} />
  </div>,
   document.getElementById('root')
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to transform your source code for the browser, replacing require calls with the actual module code. Take a look at these utilities:

- http://browserify.org/ - it does exactly the transformation you need
- https://webpack.github.io/ - a more complicated web packaging framework, with lots of other useful features.

I recommend the second.